# Rename workbench on FME Server

Tags: fme-form, fme-flow

I'd like to change the name of a workbench I published on FME Server. I'm afraid I didn't find a way to do this. 
As I want to keep the history of commits I cannot add the workbench as an new file to the repository.

FME Server Version 2019.2.1

Comment: What version are you on? you can rename using the REST API? https://knowledge.safe.com/questions/103348/automateschedule-push-from-fme-cloudserver-to-remo.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We finally found a way to rename the workbench. It's not by using the user interface, but changing it directly in the fmeserver database (PostgreSQL). Therefore you change the name in the tables "fme_item" and "fme_commits" and change also the fmw workbench name that is stored on the server (AppData-folder).

But I think one has to be **very careful** with changing something in the database and it's not really recommendable, because one can easily break something, so the enhancement request Mark Ireland mentioned is still very useful and needed!

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, I don't think that's possible. The only way would be to download all of the previously committed versions, and republish them all under the new name. Not a particularly attractive option.

This enhancement request has been filed already (ref: FMESERVER-14503) so I'll tag this thread so that the developers are aware of the need.